# Singletons between Express requests

Tags: node.js, express

With Express on Node....

How to use a singleton between requests per client?  Looking to make a type of dispatcher server-side that should be a singleton per client (once identified by passport).  Is there module support or do people just dump into a hash by session identifier?

Comment: Look at the session middleware.

Comment: what you are asking  makes little sense.How would your singleton(which would not be one since there is one per client,therefore many) knows who is whom? use sessions,like everyone else.

Comment: Singleton in respect to context, being the caller.

Comment: @SLaks, the MemoryStore uses an array keyed of sid (session id).  Thanks for the tip.